# Reformat list data to a specific dataframe format

Tags: r

I have to specify some parameters in an exact format, to be able to work in a function. Difficult to explain but here is some example data in that format that I need.

```
dftargets=list(
  age=list("age1824"=0.1, "age2534"=0.25, "age3544"=0.3, "age4554"=0.25, "age55+"=0.1), 
  sex=list('Male'=0.49, 'Female'=0.51))

> dftargets
$age
$age$age1824
[1] 0.1

$age$age2534
[1] 0.25

$age$age3544
[1] 0.3

$age$age4554
[1] 0.25

$age$`age55+`
[1] 0.1


$sex
$sex$Male
[1] 0.49

$sex$Female
[1] 0.51
```

my data is in this format as separate lists.

```
age_label <- c("age1824", "age2534", "age3544", "age4554", "age55+")
age_values <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1)
sex_label <- c("Male", "Female")
sex_values <- c(0.49, 0.51)
```

Is there a way to coerce my data from separate lists to the above dataframe format? I know I can type it in, but would like to know if there is an easier way. Any help greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be better methods, but the below would work:

```
age <- as.list(age_values)
names(age)<-age_label

sex <- as.list(sex_values)
names(sex) <- sex_label

dftargets=list(age=age,sex=sex)
names(dftargets)<-c("age","sex")
```

Comment: I think there is no need for `names(dftargets)<-c("age","sex")` as you are setting them already in the line before `list(age=age,sex=sex)`

Comment: Your right, I changed the code and forgot to remove the last line (actually I think it reads better including it - even though superfluous in current form)

Comment: No need for `add.list()` either here, right? Nice answer, Greg!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner:

```
age_label <- c("age1824", "age2534", "age3544", "age4554", "age55+")
age_values <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1)
sex_label <- c("Male", "Female")
sex_values <- c(0.49, 0.51)

dftargets <- list(age = as.list(setNames(age_values,age_label)), 
                  sex = as.list(setNames(sex_values,sex_label)))
dftargets
#> $age
#> $age$age1824
#> [1] 0.1
#> 
#> $age$age2534
#> [1] 0.25
#> 
#> $age$age3544
#> [1] 0.3
#> 
#> $age$age4554
#> [1] 0.25
#> 
#> $age$`age55+`
#> [1] 0.1
#> 
#> 
#> $sex
#> $sex$Male
#> [1] 0.49
#> 
#> $sex$Female
#> [1] 0.51
Created on 2021-07-01 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case there are more than one in each given group `split` could be used:

```
list(age = split(age_values, age_label)
   , sex = split(sex_values, sex_label))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
age_label <- c("age1824", "age2534", "age3544", "age4554", "age55+")
age_values <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.3, 0.25, 0.1)
sex_label <- c("Male", "Female")
sex_values <- c(0.49, 0.51)

names(age_values) <- age_label
names(sex_values) <- sex_label

dft <- list()
dft[["age"]] <- age_values
dft[["sex"]] <- sex_values
dft
```